# my open ai gpt-4-vision-preview model does not work

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, openai-api, gpt-4

I am working from Google Colab, I want the model to create the meta descriptions of about 400 images that I have in Google Drive. It worked relatively well for the first 100 images and then it didn't, and now it just writes "error" in the resulting excel. I attach the code here:

```
import os
import base64
import requests
import pandas as pd
from google.colab import drive


drive.mount('/content/drive')


image_folder = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Work related/FS/Imagenes/Metadescripciones HC '


api_key = 'my api code goes here XXXXX'


def encode_image(image_path):
    with open(image_path, "rb") as image_file:
        return base64.b64encode(image_file.read()).decode('utf-8')


headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {api_key}"
}


results_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Nombre del Archivo', 'Metadescripcion'])


for filename in os.listdir(image_folder):
    if filename.endswith((".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg")):  # Asegúrate de que es una imagen
        image_path = os.path.join(image_folder, filename)
        base64_image = encode_image(image_path)

        
        payload = {
            "model": "gpt-4-vision-preview",
            "messages": [
                {
                    "role": "user",
                    "content": [
                        {
                            "type": "text",
                            "text": "Write a meta description for the image of this product, optimized for SEO and in less than 150 words"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "image_url",
                            "image_url": {
                                "url": f"data:image/jpeg;base64,{base64_image}",
                                "detail": "low"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "max_tokens": 400
        }

        
        response = requests.post("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", headers=headers, json=payload)
        response_json = response.json()
        metadescription = response_json['choices'][0]['message']['content'] if response.status_code == 200 else 'Error'

        
        new_row = pd.DataFrame({'Nombre del Archivo': [filename], 'Metadescripcion': [metadescription]})
        results_df = pd.concat([results_df, new_row], ignore_index=True)



results_df.to_excel('/content/drive/MyDrive/Work related/FS/Imagenes/Metadescripciones.xlsx', index=False)
```

I have tried changing the max_tokens and changing the image folder path

Comment: it writes **Error** because you are assigning `metadescription` as `Error` if `response.status_code` is not _200_. Check the actual error first and post it here.

Answer (score 0):

gpt-4-vision has rate limits depending on your usage tier. In some cases it is 100, for some its more.

https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/rate-limits/usage-tiers?context=tier-free

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).